# Decompose a finite dimensional vector space into a direct sum of $1$-dimensional sub-spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, with $\dim V= n$, for some  $n\geq 1$.

Prove that there exist $1$-dimensional sub-spaces $U_1, ...., U_n$ of $V$ such that $V = U_1 \oplus... \oplus U_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is given that $\dim V = n$ so you can find a basis $v_1,...,v_n$.

Now let $U_i:=\text{span} \{v_i\}$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ and you're done.

Comment: So from what i first understood, 1-dimensional means n=1. Therefore $U_1 := span\{u_1\}$  so $V=U_1$...is that correct or do i not understand something.

Comment: @noobisko $n=\dim V$. If a vector space $U$ is $1$-dimensional that means that $\dim U = 1$. In my answer $U_i$ is spanned by one non-zero vector (by $v_i$) and so it has dimension $1$.